# Laravel 5.2 and jQuery validation:Trying to get property of Non-Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using jQuery validation plugin to validate username is already existing or not.

**Documentation of validation plugin says:**

> The serverside resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated
>   element and its value as a GET parameter. The serverside response must
>   be a JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements, and can be
>   "false", undefined, or null for invalid elements, using the default
>   error message. If the serverside response is a string, eg. "That name
>   is already taken, try peter123 instead", this string will be displayed
>   as a custom error message in place of the default.

**Laravel controller:**

```
public function verifyName(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->input('name', '');
    $user = User::where('name', $username)->first();
    if ($username == $user->name) {
        return json_encode(false);
    }else{
        return json_encode(true);
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $("#register").validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    rangelength: [4, 30],
                    remote: {
                        url: "{{ url('services/validation/verify_name') }}",
                        type: "post"
                    }
                }
            },
            errorClass: "has-danger",
            validClass: "has-success",
            //success: "valid",

            highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).fadeOut(function () {
                    $(element).fadeIn();
                });
                $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass(errorClass);
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass(errorClass);
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Question:**

When `return false`, it works but when `return true`, there is an error: "Trying to get property of non-object"，I don't know why.

Comment: `var_dump` the `$user` object and see what class it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a user record with the given `$username`, then your `$user` variable is going to be `null`. If `$user` is `null`, when you try to access `$user->name` in your if statement, you'll get the `"Trying to get property of non-object"` error.

You want to do something like this:

```
public function verifyName(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->input('name', '');
    $user = User::where('name', $username)->first();

    // if the user was found, this will be true;
    // if the user wasn't found, $user will be null and this will be false
    if ($user) {
        return json_encode(false);
    } else {
        return json_encode(true);
    }
}
```